# Are there feature selection algorithms that can be applied to categorical data inputs?

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

I am training a neural network which has 10 or so categorical inputs. After one-hot encoding these categorical inputs I end up feeding around 500 inputs into the network.

I would love to be able to ascertain the importance of each of my categorical inputs. Scikit-learn has [numerous feature importance algorithms](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html), however can any of these be applied to categorical data inputs? All of the examples use numerical inputs.

I could apply these methods to the one-hot encoded inputs, but how would I extract the meaning after applying to binarised inputs? How does one go about judging feature importance on categorical inputs?

Comment: I've successfully used [`mutual_info_score`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_classif.html#sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_classif) which supports `discrete_features=True`.

Comment: Have a look at http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#encoding-categorical-features

Comment: Careful using one-hot encoding because you've [increased the dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality) of your feature space by a factor of 50. You might also consider using random forest instead of a neural network because the random forest method has a feature importance characterization built-in.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.
@IgorRaush, I can use the mutual_info_classif function like this:
`l_importance = mutual_info_classif(X, y, discrete_features=True)`

But can you confirm the way I encode my discrete features in the X array. Obviously it has to be a numpy array so inputs most be encoded. Can I use the discrete indices? If I binarised the inputs it would be hard to extract the meaning from the function output as the features are so 'split'.

If these were my inputs:
`X = [['A', 'X', 'alpha'],
     ['B', 'X', 'beta'],
     ['B', 'Y', 'gamma']]`

How would I encode? Thanks -

Comment: @VivekKumar thanks for your reply. I know how to encode categorical inputs. Are you implying that best practice is to run standard feature selection algorithms on one-hot encoded inputs? If that is the case, how would you wrap up the outputs to ascertain the importance of each feature, and not each of its one-hot encoded column? Thanks

Comment: @A555h5 seems that it doesn't actually need to be a Numpy array, the list you gave works just fine as an input (although you could use a Numpy array with `dtype=np.str` which contains strings and it would also work).

Comment: In general, for situations like this, you would use an index encoding where each level of the categorical feature is mapped to an integer 0, 1, etc. Take a look at [`LabelEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder) in Scikit-learn or [categorical series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) in Pandas.

Comment: In response to your question to Vivek, it depends on what you're trying to accomplish. You can use an importance metric to prune entire features ("feature selection"), or you can one-hot encode them and prune only certain levels ("value selection"). I've seen both ways used.

Comment: Thanks for your answers @IgorRaush - a quick question though. If I had a mix of both categorical and numeric features in the same dataset, how would I encode then? I would like to consider them together, as I need to know their mutual effect on each other. Should I treat the numeric as categorical (this seems wrong as you lose the magnitude), or use the index encoding method on the categorical ones and combine with the numeric? Thanks again

Comment: In some cases it may be worth exploring your dataset outside of scikit-learn before diving into it. I usually use Weka's GUI to play around a little. In Weka, you can visualize and evaluate features using several algorithms. Trim your dataset a little if it's too big. Get Weka here: http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/ More info on Attribute selection here: http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/DATAMINING/Attribute+Selection

Answer (score 2):

Using the feature selection algorithms on one hot encoding might be miss leading due to the relations between the encoded features. For example, if you encode a feature of n values into n features and you have n-1 of the m selected, the last feature is not needed.

Since the number of your features is quite low (~10), feature selection not help you so much since you'll probably be able to reduce only few of them without loosing too much information.

You wrote that the one hot encoding turns the 10 features into 500, meaning that each feature has about 50 values. In this case you might be more interested in discretisation algorithms, manipulating on the values themselves. If there is an implied order on the values, you can use algorithms for continuos [features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretization_of_continuous_features). Another option is simply to omit rare values or values without a strong correlation to the concept.

In case that you use feature selection, most algorithms will work on categorial data but you should beware of corner cases. For example, the mutual information, suggested by @Igor Raush is an excellent measure. However, features with many values tend to have higher entropy than feature withe less values. That in turn might lead into higher mutual information and a bias into features of many values. A way to cope with this problem is to normalize by dividing the mutual information by the feature entropy.

Another set of feature selection algorithms that might help you are the [wrappers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection#Wrapper_method). They actually delegate the learning to the classification algorithm and therefore they are indifferent of the representation as long as the classification algorithm can cope with it.